# What is the probability of getting multiple choice question correct

Tags: probability

One multiple choice question has 4 choices to choose from. Students must choose 2 correct answers from the 4 choices in order to pass. What is the probability of passing this question?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ unordered pairs of two choices. If the student chooses at random, each of these pairs is equally probable, so the probability of choosing the correct pair is $1/6$.

Comment: what would I enter into x, numtrial and p if I were to work out the probability on the calculator?

Comment: Doing that kind of calculation would assume you already know the probability. For example, if you set $x=10$, $p=1/6$, $n=25$, the calculator would give the probability of getting exactly 10 questions right on a test with 25 of such questions.